# How do I make email replies go to the same folder as the email from earlier in the same conversation?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter, rules

Microsoft Outlook lets you set rules to sort incoming mail into the appropriate folder.  Sometimes I get an email that the rules do not or can not sort, so I put it in the appropriate folder manually.

The problem with this is that if someone replies to the conversation, I have to also move that reply into the same folder as the parent email in the chain.

How do I make Outlook sort an email reply into the same folder as the email it is replying to?

Comment: What version of Outlook are you on? Windows or Mac?

Comment: @Sun Outlook 2010 on Windows 7

Comment: Can you explain why it's important to have email replies to a thread be in the same folder? When you start using outlook 2013 or outlook 2016, the clean up folders feature is gonna blow your mind.

Comment: @Sun Say someone sends out an office wide email asking where the next office happy hour should be.  My rules won't catch that email, so I need to manually file it under "Office Discussion".  I want the 10+ replies recommending local bars to go into that folder instead of cluttering my Inbox.

Answer (score 2):

This is for Outlook 2013:

- Go to File > Options
- Mail
- Make sure the checkbox for "When reply to a message that is not in the Inbox, save the reply in the same folder' is on

[image: File > Options]

Comment: This option saves *my* reply in the same folder, instead of the 'sent messages' folder.  I want to see other people's replies in the same folder.

Comment: conversation view finds the email in other folders https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-on-or-off-Conversations-arrangement-in-the-message-list-96b6b5ea-def6-4a85-be5a-6fce272fe569

Comment: I appreciate your help, Sun. Conversation view lets me see it in the destination folder, but it also puts it in the Inbox.  I want it to go directly to the folder and skip the Inbox.

Comment: I'm afraid in Outlook 2010 there isn't a way through the application. Even in Outlook 2013, you have to use [Outlook VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj973082.aspx) to get a handle on moving same conversations to a folder that is not the Inbox. You'd have to pay someone to write code that would do this for you. I feel what I gave you is free, good enough and works for me on a daily basis for my purposes. It is 2016, do we really need to hold to concepts such as folders? We have tags and search for a reason.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically tag incoming email with the same tag that a message from earlier in the conversation has?

Comment: Not really. You can set up a rule to tag a message based on the keywords in a subject, but you'd have to do that manually for each conversation.

Comment: Search in email clients is slow

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, and I found exactly what I was looking for here:

[Move incoming Outlook emails to folder containing previous conversation](https://superuser.com/questions/986761/move-incoming-outlook-emails-to-folder-containing-previous-conversation)

> There is a "move" ribbon/action in outlook, the last item of it is "Always move messages in this conversation...". There you can specify, where to move the messages that arrive for a specific conversation. Unfortunatly you will have to do this for every conversation (not for every mail though). So far the fastest solution i could find for this problem.

Comment: Please post answer and then references.